# How to validation a list with hapijs joi framework in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, joi

I want to validation the datatype like an array in javascript.

the origin data like:

```
"dams":[
{"id": 1, "name": "Burrinjuck Dam", "self": "",…},
{"id": 2, "name": "Blowering Dam", "self": "",…}
]
```

The number of elements is not sure, but each element is the same type of dam object.
Do Joi provider any method to validate a list of same type elements?

Comment: Like mentioned here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/37744483/4636715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine **Joi.array().items()** with **Joi.object()**, and do something like this:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
   damns: Joi.array().items(
       Joi.object().keys({
             id: Joi.string(),
             name: Joi.string(),
             self: Joi.string()
       })
   )
});
```